# Largest Singular Value of Triangular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

Let $R\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be an upper triangular matrix.

The eigenvalues of $R$ is then its diagonal entries, that is, $(R_{ii}, e_i)$ is an eigenpair of $R$ since $Re_i=R_{ii}e_i$.

Is it possible to bound the largest singular value $\sigma_\max (R)=\sqrt{\lambda_\max (RR^T)}$ by the diagonal entries of $R$?

---

[Weyl's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_between_eigenvalues_and_singular_values) tells us $\lambda_\max \le \sigma_\max$ which is the wrong direction. But maybe we can get something like $\sigma_\max < \lambda_\max^2$ assuming $\lambda_\max>1$? Or can the largest singular value be arbitrarily larger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is it possible to bound the largest singular value $\sigma_\max (R)=\sqrt{\lambda_\max (RR^T)}$ by the diagonal entries of $R$?*
If you look at the unbounded nature of the Frobenius norm, the answer of course is no.

with standard basis vectors $\mathbf e_k$, consider
$R' := R +\alpha \mathbf e_1\mathbf e_d^T$
$R$ and $R'$ have the same diagonal entries and hence would have the same purported fixed upper bound $M$. Yet by selecting large enough $\alpha$ we have
$M\lt \frac{1}{d}\big \Vert R'\big\Vert_F \leq \sigma_1$